# How to pass multiple array value generated by jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

Here is jQuery code. it works fine at xampp and my server. 
I would like to add this code into Laravel. Since I post here I recived kind help but still I couldn't get array value at Laravel.

Whole code is here

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/ec15ytmq/23/)

What I tried that I'm guessing this input field has no "name=" so I add name but it can not pass values.

```
<div class="fieldContainer">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="text" class="search" data-ref="${ref}" placeholder="Type something" class="form-control" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
      <span class="search-clear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" data-ref="${ref}"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group resultUl" data-ref="${ref}"></ul>
    </div>
```

At xampp or with out Laravel (my server ) I can get array value using below code.

```
echo var_dump($_POST["search_1"]);
```

I wrote below code in Laravel. but I'm not sure to how to write in case of multipule array.

now I got error is

> Undefined index: search_1

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {   
       $post_data = $request::all();
       $search_1 = $request::all();
       return view('pn.conf',compact('post_data'),compact('search_1'));
    }
```

Could someone teach me what is wrong my code please?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `compact('search_1')` to the second argument of the `view` method:

```
return view('pn.conf', compact('post_data', 'search_1'));
```

The third argument of the `view` method is used to set the status to something else than 200.

You can read the definition [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_view).

Now you can use those variables in your blade view just like this:

```
{{ $search_1 }}
```

Take note that `$request->all()` will return all fields from the request. Use the `input()` method instead:

```
$search_1 = $request->input('search_1');
```

`search_1` has to be the name property on the form, or the key in the payload of your json.

Comment: Dear @piscator Thank you very much for answer. I wrote as you teach me but I still got this error.   ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined index: search_1 what else you could think my problem?  I wrote echo var_dump($_POST["search_1"]); at blade file

Comment: Dear @piscator Thank you for answering me back then. I've been trying to solve my issue. but still I couldn't find a goal. Could you teach me some advice please?

Comment: @machagr: You can check the additions in my answer. Since there is quite some room for improvement in your code it would be a good investment of your time to read a tutorial about jQuery / Ajax / Laravel. Good luck!

Comment: Dear @piscator Thank you very much for comment. I fix my code what you told me. but still same... I have one concern. I looked Environment & details In [POST Data] There is no search_1 data. that mean I can't get a search_1 data. Am I right? I can get other all values which are 'post_data' . As I explain first. Without Laravel I can recive search_1 and search_2 data.3 4 5 all value   There is no search_1 name or value at Environment & details In [POST Data] . so I already can't recived value ? Can you revice the sear_1 2 3 value using this JS file in Laravel?